# A variables cache system replacement for APC and Memcache?

Tags: php, apache, caching, memcached, apc

As we knew that APC and Memcache is good cache system for storing value.

And APC user cache is much faster than Memcache to store simple, tiny size value, because APC is a local-based cache system without creating a connection as Memcache.

But I found that using `apc_store()` to save the value with TTL will create many fragmentation easily and will restart the APC service if the fragmentation is too high.

Is there any replacement for storing value on PHP+Apache? Or the solutions to handle the fragmentation on APC?

I need a cache system to store value with TTL. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread.

Take a look at this opcode cachers:
[List of PHP accelerators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators)